# Python - Matching Objects Based on List Position

Tags: python, loops, indexing

I am trying to match objects in a list, based on their positions in a list.  The position in the list is always the same for a specific CSV, but varies based on client.

I have a Dictionary that contains 5 clients and the column in the CSV where the data is contained:

```
d = {'Client1':{
                'file1DataPositions':[1,3,5,6,9],
                'file2DataPositions':[2,4,5,7,8]},
     'Client2':{
                'file1DataPositions':[3,4,5,6,7],
                'file2DataPositions':[1,5,7,8,9]},
     'Client3':{
                'file1DataPositions':[2,6,7,8,9],
                'file2DataPositions':[1,2,7,8,9]},
     'Client4':{
                'file1DataPositions':[2,3,4,6,6],
                'file2DataPositions':[1,3,5,7,9]},
     'Client5':{
                'file1DataPositions':[2,4,6,8,9],
                'file2DataPositions':[5,6,7,8,9]}
     }
```

I have a populated, embedded list (a parsed CSV):

```
l = [['data1','123','ABC','CompanyName','Employee1','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork'],
     ['data2','456','DEF','CompanyName','Employee2','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork'],
     ['data3','789','GHI','CompanyName','Employee3','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork'],
     ['data4','012','JKL','CompanyName','Employee4','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork']]
```

Based on the position of the index in the embedded list, I would like to check to see if the index matches:

```
def iterationTest():
    for item in l:
        for lis in item:
            if lis.index() == d['Client1']['file1DataPositions']:
                print('Match Found')

iterationTest()
```

When I run this, I get an: "index() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)" error.

Is there a correct way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: `if lis.index()` what are you checking here? What index?

Comment: The [`index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) method of a list requires at least one argument — the value of the element to find the index of the first occurrence of.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the `index` of `lis` is `in` `d['Client1']['file1DataPositions']`, for eg in the list `[1,3,5,6,9]`?

Comment: The index of what matches what are you trying to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate()`:

```
def iterationTest():
    for item in l:
        for idx, lis in enumerate(item):
            if idx in d['Client1']['file1DataPositions']:
                print('Match Found')

iterationTest()
```

This will iterate over each `lis` in `item`, and at each stage in the loop it will provide access to both `lis` and its index, `idx` (which you use for comparison).

Comment: YES!  "If you are trying to check if the idx of lis is in d['Client1']['file1DataPositions'], use if idx in d['Client1']['file1DataPositions']:"     That is exactly what I was trying to do.  I will go ahead and accept this answer!

Answer (score 0):

what you exactly trying to do? you are looking for index of list?
i'm guessing you are trying to do this:

```
d = {'Client1':{
                'file1DataPositions':[1,3,5,6,9],
                'file2DataPositions':[2,4,5,7,8]},
     'Client2':{
                'file1DataPositions':[3,4,5,6,7],
                'file2DataPositions':[1,5,7,8,9]},
     'Client3':{
                'file1DataPositions':[2,6,7,8,9],
                'file2DataPositions':[1,2,7,8,9]},
     'Client4':{
                'file1DataPositions':[2,3,4,6,6],
                'file2DataPositions':[1,3,5,7,9]},
     'Client5':{
                'file1DataPositions':[2,4,6,8,9],
                'file2DataPositions':[5,6,7,8,9]}
     }
l = [['data1','123','ABC','CompanyName','Employee1','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork'],
     ['data2','456','DEF','CompanyName','Employee2','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork'],
     ['data3','789','GHI','CompanyName','Employee3','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork'],
     ['data4','012','JKL','CompanyName','Employee4','15','123 Notareallstreet','Bobs Trucks','Newyork']]

def iterationTest(Preview=True):
    for clientKey , clientValue in d.iteritems():
        for dataKey, dataValue in clientValue.iteritems():
            if Preview:
                print "Data Position: %s"%dataKey
            for eachnum in dataValue:
                if eachnum <= len(l[0])-1:
                    if Preview:
                        print "Match Number: %s"%eachnum
                        print "Number Value: %s"%l[0][eachnum]
                        print "------------------------------"
            if Preview:
                print "=============================="

iterationTest()
```